# Can't draw in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

I'm trying to design a simple program that I can draw inside of. I want points to be drawn on the screen when the mouse is clicked. I am trying to use QPainter, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended (That is to say, when I click, nothing is drawn on the screen). Any help would be appreciated.

[Link to the code](https://pastebin.com/TUcXQLa6)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys, random


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 190)
        self.setWindowTitle('Draw')
        self.y = 0
        self.x = 0
        self.show()

    def drawPoints(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)
        size = self.size()
        qp.drawPoint(self.x, self.y)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        pos = QMouseEvent.pos()
        self.x = pos.x()
        self.y = pos.y()
        self.drawPoints(self.qp)
    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        self.qp.end()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working as intended." is *not* a valid problem specification.

Comment: When i say that, I mean that when i click nothing happens

Comment: Then you should put that in your question instead of making a bunch of clarifying comments.

Comment: @VoxelVortexGaming Did my answer help you?

Comment: It definitely gives a great starting point, although when you move your cursor only the original point is drawn, rather than a ton of points following around your cursor